# Calculating number of residents living within service areas using ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.4, intersect

I'm trying to build a Map of service areas of several facilities. In addition, I want to calculate the number of residents living within those service areas.

Therefore I have a Layer of Census-Blocks which I want to intersect with the new layer of my service areas. The problem is now that I get a new Layer of Blocks lying within my service areas but I don't get any attributes with information about shape length, shape area or amount of residents. Where is my mistake?

Picture 1: Model to build Service Area and intersect with census blocks to calculate residents within

[image: Model to build Service Area and intersect with census blocks to calculate residents within]

Picture 2: Service Area

[image: Service Area]

Picture 3: Intersection of Census-Blocks (RED) and Blocks within Service Area (GREEN)

[image: Intersection of Census-Blocks (RED) and Blocks within Service Area (GREEN)]

Comment: Are you selecting or spatial joining the service area layer to the census layer?  After doing this you may then summarize the selected or joined features by the population field.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  It sounds like you think most of your model is working so we need you to focus your question down to a test model that includes only the elements directly related to where you are stuck.